# How to install two elasticsearch version to support two different Magento version?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.3.4, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

I have two Magento 2 projects with different versions. One Magento version support Elasticsearch 7+ and another supports ElasticSearch 6+. I have installed ES7 which is working fine. How can I install another ElasticSearch 6 to support another project?

Answer (score 0):

Just runs few ES version on different ports

Setups correct ES port in each Magento instance

As alternative you can use something like Docker to install different version in separate containers with the same idea about listening port